# How do I remove a trailing comma from a string

Tags: powershell, character, trim

I have a string producing results in PowerShell being separated by a comma, which is fine, but I don't want the last comma.

I understand a Trim function is required, but I can't seem to get it to work. Maybe i've been trying it in the wrong place?

I need it to return three "Site Codes, each separated with a comma, and no comma at the end. I need to know where to add the trim bit really.

```
$UKPRN = "10007405"
$str_sites = "A4EYORK,AVLEEDS,BANBURY";

$sites = "";


foreach ($site in $str_sites.Split(","))
{
$sites = $sites+"'"+$site+"',"

}
Write-Output $sites;
```

Comment: Please don't post Screenshots of code, post the actual code in the question.

Comment: You shouldn't post pictures of code. We can't copy it and try it out.

Comment: Also please rephrase how the input and the expected output would look like.

Comment: I've used a code sample now.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Why can't you use an array and each string to it?

Answer (score 15):

You could just use TrimEnd()

```
$str = "string with , at the end,"
$str.TrimEnd(",")
```

Answer (score 4):

Your string building method is what is creating that issue for you in the first place. You want to quote all elements of your string correct? Quote your array elements individually then use `-join` and there will be no artifacts that you have to deal with.

```
$sites = "A4EYORK,AVLEEDS,BANBURY"
($sites.split(",") | ForEach-Object{"'$_'"}) -join ","
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str_sites = "A4EYORK,AVLEEDS,BANBURY"

$sites = $str_sites.Split(",") | % { "'{0}'" -f $_ }

Write-Output ($sites -join ',')
```

`$sites` is array, joined with ',' by using `-join` operator.
For more information about `-join`, see the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally use `String.Split()` and `String.Join()` for this, but since all of your terms are made up by word characters, you could easily do this with a simple regex replacement pattern as well:

```
$str_sites = $str_sites -replace '\b(\w+)\b',"'`$1'"
```

Comment: I had thought about adding in that but wanted to keep it simple.